# NAT and remember the original IP address?

Tags: nat, gateway

Is it possible to do NAT and remember the original IP address?

For example, on my gateway, I might want to NAT all outgoing IP traffic to itself, and then write some server software to intercept the traffic. My software will need to know the original destination IP.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to do all this in shell scripting or is another programming language an option?

Comment: Take a look at [netfilter.org](https://www.netfilter.org). Depending on what kind of stuff you are wanting to write, the libraries that they support can propagate packet filtering up into userland where you could do whatever you wanted to...

Comment: Any language.  Preferably not c, but I might take what I can get.  I'm considering node.js.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. It fills my head with all sorts of ideas, only I am not exactly sure what they are.